# CRM 2016: error message dialog does not show up

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm

In Offer screen, I have an subgrid of ProductOffer can be added.
I have a PreCreate ProductOffer plugin which checks for some conditions to show error message and stop creating.

So in this plugin I added:

```
throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("My message");
```

But no dialog message is shown up but an error notification on top of the subgrid with message: "***ISV code aborted the operation***".

Please tell me why is my message not displayed? And how to solve this?

Thank you verymuch.

Comment: What action do you take for your plugin to fire?  Is it when you click the + button to add a new Product Offer?

Comment: Yes, you are right, I click the + button, and the oncreate plugin (of product offer) is called.

Comment: Does a quick create form pop up and you fill that out and save the Product Offer?  Or does the full create form come up?

Comment: Just an adding row inside the subgrid where I can choose a product, then the product offer is automatically created for me, no any form or popup displayed.

Comment: Sounds like you're talking about custom entities and some sort of custom sub-grid control which is why you're not seeing the standard plugin error pop-up.  I'm guessing that the custom sub-grid control catches the error and displays it via that little notification you describe.  I would contact the vendor and ask them if there is are any other options for displaying the error.

Comment: Yes, right. Thanks for your efford, please tell me if you have any information.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109230/discussion-between-hong-nguyen-and-polshgiant).

Comment: Which browser are you using: IE, Chrome, FF, other?

Comment: I haven't been able to pinpoint your issue exactly but this document may have some clues for you. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics/crm-customer-center/Microsoft_Dynamics_CRM_2016_Readme.htm

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing is the normal expected behavior in CRM based on my experience with it.  I've done the same thing with the line item sub-grid on the `Quote` form.  I have a plugin that applies some business logic on create of a `QuoteDetail` record and prevents the user from doing certain things.  When the plugin throws an exception the only thing displayed is the error message above the grid as you described.  My guess is that the sub-grid is somewhat isolated from the main form controls and you don't get the normal full business process error pop-up because it was an exception on a related entity and not on the main entity you're viewing in the form.  I have not found any way around this and I believe it would need to be a product feature request on connect.microsoft.com for MS to consider changing.